# "a hundred" vs. "a hundred of"

Tags: grammatical-number, style

What is the difference between these two sentences?

1) I have interviewed more than a hundred **of** the greatest politicians, artists …

2) I have interviewed more than a hundred politicians, artists …

Comment: The first adds the modifier "of the greatest" meaning you only interviewed the best of the group instead of a random sampling.  If the 'of' os tripping you up, you could also say: "more than a hundred politicians , artists, ... that are the greatest in their fields of study."  The "of" here allows you to modify the whole group here.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to look at the *entire* difference:

```
I have interviewed more than a hundred *of the greatest* politicians, artists …
```

vs

```
 I have interviewed more than a hundred politicians, artists …
```

The difference is that in the former you are making the distinction of having interviewed a particular kind of politicians and artists.  While the latter only says that a certain number of people were interviewed, the former makes a point of that the hundred people are among the greatest.

It doesn't only work with hundreds, it is the same with singular nouns:

```
I ate one banana...
```

vs

```
I ate one of the greatest bananas...
```

Answer (score -4):

**A hundred of** means that there are more then hundred  of artists, politicians...

**A hundred**  means that there COULD be a little bit more than hundred or exactly one hundred

Comment: I disagree that "a hundred of" means "more than"

Comment: With every disagreement must come an explanation...

Comment: _There were 650 paintings in the museum, but I only saw a hundred of them_. (That doesn't mean I saw 110 paintings, it means I saw 100.)

Comment: No it doesn't, but I only saw a hundred would mean that you saw 100  exactly, a hundred of them would mean a lot more than hundred...

Comment: _There were 650 paintings in the museum. I saw a hundred of them._ Even with the "only" removed, I still don't see how "a hundred of" in that sentence implies more than 100.

Comment: _"There were two apples on the table.  I ate one of them."_    This means that one apple was eaten, one was left behind.  It is not ambiguous.  Now consider: _"There were two apples on the table.  I ate one apple."_  The only way this could have a different meaning is if the apple I ate did not come from the table.  If my apple that was eaten had been on the table, the two sentences have exactly the same meaning.  _Of_ serves to restrict which apples were eaten or which paintings were seen.  It does not change the count of eaten or seen items in any way.

Comment: Given that  _"there were 650 paintings in the museum..."_  the difference between _"...I saw a hundred paintings."_ and _"... I saw a hundred of them."_ is only that in the second sentence we have explicitly stated that the paintings I saw were in the museum, rather than outside, or on my cellphone.  In both cases I saw 100 paintings.  (Native AmE)

Comment: Wow! Quite a learning experience from the above discussion. Thank you all.